# Codeigniter4 Routing Failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

I have a problem with routing on my website as it's not working at all. At the beginning I wanted to have different Controllers for differetn tabs, but in the end I have changed that to view pages from the Home controller, but even that doesnt work.

Here is my Home controller - index and connection to Model works fine but the travel() function doesnt

```
    <?php 
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\HomeMod;
use \Codeigniter\Controller;

class Home extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        $this->homeMod = new HomeMod();
        $data = array();
        $data['total'] = number_format($this->totalCases('total'));
    
    
        echo view('header');    
        echo view('welcome_message', $data);
        echo view('footer');
    }
    protected function totalCases(String $columnName) : String{
        $result = $this->homeMod->findColumn($columnName);
        return count($result) > 0 ? $result[0] : "0";
    } 


    public function travel() {
        return view('travel');
    }
    public function getPostCodeCases() {
        if(!IS_AJAX) return;
        var_dump("inside");
        die();
    } 
}
```

I cannot reach the getPostCodeCases() function either (the ajax call in js file works fine, its just not reaching this function).

And my routes file - as you can see i have tries with different variations

```
    $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
 // $routes->get('/getPostCodeCases', 'Home::getPostCodeCases');
    $routes->post('/getPostCodeCases', 'Home::getPostCodeCases');
    $routes->match(['get', 'post'],'/getPostCodeCases',    'Home::getPostCodeCases');
    $routes->get("travel", "Travel::index");

 // $routes->add('/travel', 'Travel::index');
// $routes->add('travel', 'Home::travel');
// $routes->add('/travel/(:any)', 'Travel::index');
```

My base url: https://localhost/CI and  $indexPage = '' (in App.php).
I am sure I have missed something, somewhere but not sure where...

Could someone help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Comment: Ah i found error in my .htaccess file (on root level) had to add /projectName/ next to RewriteBase